# GTM Click Event Works in Preview, but Misfires When Live

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have created a custom attribute that can be added to elements to track clicks on them. When I test the event with preview mode, it works perfectly. However, when live, I'm getting a lot of undefined events from links I am not trying to track.

The idea is I want to be able to add **data-track-click** to any element and begin tracking events from it. That attribute would also hold the event category, action, label, and value as such: **data-track-click="Category, Action, Label, Value"**. In testing this works perfectly. It only fires on elements that contain this attribute, and the labels are parsed properly in GTM. But apparently, when live the tag starts firing on many element clicks that do not contain the **data-track-click** attribute.

I tested using Google Analytics Debugger and preserve the log in my console to record between pages, I saw nothing wrong. I also saw nothing wrong in a recording with Tag Assistant. I cannot replicate all of the erroneous hits I am seeing in Google Analytics and have no idea how to fix this.

I'm pretty certain this has to do with my event trigger. Possibly the regex /^.+$/ is being interpreted even when empty? But why would that happen? Is it also possible that past configurations have been cached? Because I certainly had some mistakes before.

Here's the auto-event variable:
[image]

And here is the event:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening that sometimes GTM it triggering a click on child DOM elements. For example, if you have this DOM:

```
<div data-track-click="Category, Action, Label, Value">
    <span>A</span>
    <a>B</a>
</div>
```

Then when you click on `A` then GTM will fire click on `span` which doesn't have `data-track-click`.

**My solution is**:

1. Create a trigger with this condition: `Click Element` - `matches CSS selector` - `[data-track-click], [data-track-click] *`. Which will capture `data-track-click` and all his childs [image]
2. Create JS variable, which will return `data-track-click` attribute value from click element or from closest parent element which has this attribute.

For Category:

```
function() {
    var el = {{Click Element}}
    while (el.getAttribute("data-track-click") == null && el !=null) {
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    if (el != null) {
        var attr = el.getAttribute("data-track-click");
        return attr.split(',')[0].trim();
    }
    return "";
}
```

For Action:

```
function() {
    var el = {{Click Element}}
    while (el.getAttribute("data-track-click") == null && el !=null) {
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    if (el != null) {
        var attr = el.getAttribute("data-track-click");
        return attr.split(',')[1].trim();
    }
    return "";
}
```

For Label:

```
function() {
    var el = {{Click Element}}
    while (el.getAttribute("data-track-click") == null && el !=null) {
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    if (el != null) {
        var attr = el.getAttribute("data-track-click");
        return attr.split(',')[2].trim();
    }
    return "";
}
```

3. Then create a tag which will use variables and triggers above.

P.S. To avoid caching after you changed something in GTM and published it, Just use [hard refresh](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/)